# What is the point of quote with single argument and comma? (quote ,arg)

Tags: elisp, backquote

`(quote x)` makes x not be evaluated, but adding a `,` in front of `x` within `quote` makes it evaluated. What is then the point of using quote with a single argument with a comma in front of it, like so: `(quote ,x)`?

Motivated by [line 59 from annoying arrows](https://github.com/magnars/annoying-arrows-mode.el/blob/master/annoying-arrows-mode.el#L59):

`(put (quote ,cmd) 'aa--alts ,alternatives)`

Why isn't `(put cmd 'aa-alts ,alternatives)` equally good?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The comma is used in the context of a [backquoted](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) (a.k.a. quasiquoted) list, which allows you to evaluate some portions of the list selectively.  See also [this thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list) for an example of a use for backquoting.

A couple of simple examples:

```
(setq a "a's value" b "b's value" c "c's value")
'(a  b  c)                              ; => (a b c)
`(,a b ,c)                              ; => ("a's value" b "c's value")
```

[The commas to which you're referring](https://github.com/magnars/annoying-arrows-mode.el/blob/master/annoying-arrows-mode.el#L59) are in a macro definition that, in turn, uses a backquoted `progn`:

```
(defmacro add-annoying-arrows-advice (cmd alternatives)
  `(progn
     (add-to-list 'annoying-commands (quote ,cmd))
     (put (quote ,cmd) 'aa--alts ,alternatives)
     (defadvice ,cmd (before annoying-arrows activate)
       (when annoying-arrows-mode
         (aa--maybe-complain (quote ,cmd))))))
```

`,cmd` within the backquote allows you to put the value of `cmd` in place rather than the symbol `cmd`.

Comment: Ackey, so the quote in front of `progn` means that you have to put a comma in front of stuff you want evaluated, no matter how far it is nested? (The `,cmd` is within another list, not directly within `(progn)`.)

Comment: This seems like a good opportunity to test it out!  Try evaluating `(setq a "a's value" b "b's value" c "c's value")` and then evaluating `\`(a '(,b c))`.

Comment: Other newbs: to evaluate add the text to your scratch buffer, then place your cursor at the end of the line, then press C-x-e.

Answer (score 12):

That's because it's inside a macro.  A macro needs to return a Lisp form, which then in turn gets evaluated.

For example, looking at the first invocation of this macro:

```
(add-annoying-arrows-advice previous-line '(ace-jump-mode backward-paragraph isearch-backward ido-imenu smart-up))
```

We need the expansion to contain:

```
(put 'previous-line 'aa-alts '(ace-jump-mode backward-paragraph isearch-backward ido-imenu smart-up))
```

which is what `(quote ,cmd)` achieves.  If the macro would use plain `cmd` instead, it would be kept literally and the expansion would be:

```
(put cmd 'aa-alts '(ace-jump-mode backward-paragraph isearch-backward ido-imenu smart-up))
```

which is an error, because `cmd` is not defined in the environment where the macro is invoked.

Comment: This is also a great explanation. Thanks for spelling it out.