# Backward quote, what does it mean in elisp?

Tags: backquote

I was referring the source code of `switch-to-buffer` in elisp source code, `window.el.gz`. I am seeing some backward single quotes like, `

I know single quote is used to refer to symbols but what does backward single quote do?

Source code is [here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/window.el#L7257). When to use backward quote in elisp?

Reproducing the same here,

```el
       ((pcase switch-to-buffer-in-dedicated-window
          (`nil (user-error
                 "Cannot switch buffers in a dedicated window"))
          (`prompt
           (if (y-or-n-p
                (format "Window is dedicated to %s; undedicate it"
                        (window-buffer)))
               (progn
                 (set-window-dedicated-p nil nil)
                 'force-same-window)
             (user-error
              "Cannot switch buffers in a dedicated window")))
          (`pop nil)
          (_ (set-window-dedicated-p nil nil) 'force-same-window)))
```

Comment: See also [What is the point of quote with single argument and comma?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/what-is-the-point-of-quote-with-single-argument-and-comma-quote-arg) and [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Comment: @Dan First link very interesting, thanks! In this precise question I see no reason to not "simply" use a quote instead of a backquote.  Is this some stylistic convention?

Comment: @JeanPierre: it looks like the backquote is needed in the context of `pcase`.

Comment: @Dan: Indeed I should have read https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Pattern-matching-case-statement.html#Pattern-matching-case-statement first. Trying it, I found the backquote can actually be omitted, but not replaced with a straight quote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ask Emacs.

1. `C-h i`, choose the Elisp manual.
2. `i backquote`

You'll get to node [Backquote](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html), where you'll find a complete explanation of how backquotes are used in Emacs Lisp.

The first paragraph provides a summary description:

> "Backquote constructs" allow you to quote a list, but **selectively
>   evaluate elements** of that list.  In the simplest case, it is identical
>   to the special form ‘quote’ (described in the previous section; *note
>   Quoting::).

You see there several examples, as well. Here is one:

```
`(1 2 (3 ,(+ 4 5)))
⇒ (1 2 (3 9))
```

That's equivalent to each of these, for example:

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (list 3 (+ 4 5))))

(list 1 2 (list 3 (+ 4 5)))
```

Another possible summary: backquoting gives you a simple way to see, pictorially, what list structure you are creating.  In other words, it is essentially syntactic sugar that most users typically find easier to read than the equivalent sexps that use lots of `cons`, `list`, or `append` calls.

A *typical use case* is thus for *constructing Lisp code*, especially complex code. And the **most typical** of such use cases is the code *defining a Lisp macro*, e.g., in the body of a `defmacro` expression.

All of that said, the particular case that you cite is a case of using `pcase`. If you choose to use backquoting in a typical `pcase` expression (which is what most people do) then the overall appearance is similar to that of a `cond` or a `cl-case` (Common Lisp `case`) expression.  If you do not use backquoting then your `pcase` expression (like a `defmacro` body) is likely to be more difficult to read -- the `pcase` patterns are not so obvious.