# Setting the value of a variable in Org babel system-wide header arguments

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

## The context

I always experiment with commands in the following path `$HOME/trash/experimental`. For this reason, I wanted to make all `shell` code blocks to use that directory as the default directory. I've already accomplished that by setting the following in my configuration

```
$ cat ~/.emacs.d/init.el
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages '((shell . t)))

(setq org-babel-default-header-args:shell '((:dir . "~/trash/experimental")))
```

Sometimes I also play with the `zsh` and the `dash` shell so I would also make the previous mentioned directory as the default one for code blocks whose language is any of those shells.  Similarly, I can accomplish that by setting the following in my `init.el` file.

```
$ cat ~/.emacs.d/init.el
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages '((shell . t)))

(setq org-babel-default-header-args:shell '((:dir . "~/trash/experimental")))
(setq org-babel-default-header-args:dash '((:dir . "~/trash/experimental")))
(setq org-babel-default-header-args:zsh '((:dir . "~/trash/experimental")))
```

As seen above, the path is repeated three times. In order to avoid that I defined a variable that stores the path where I experiment with commands (i.e. `~/trash/experimental`). Thus, my configration file looks  like

```
$ cat ~/.emacs.d/init.el
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages '((shell . t)))

(setf path/experiments "~/trash/experimental")

(setq org-babel-default-header-args:shell '((:dir . path/experiments)))
(setq org-babel-default-header-args:dash '((:dir . path/experiments)))
(setq org-babel-default-header-args:zsh '((:dir . path/experiments)))
```

This is where the problem comes.

## The problem

When evaluating code blocks whose language is `shell`, `dash` or `zsh`, I get the following error

```
Wrong type argument: stringp, path/experiments
```

## The question

How can I use the value of a variable so that it affects all code blocks whose language is `zsh`, `dash` or `shell`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backward quote, what does it mean in elisp?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27007/backward-quote-what-does-it-mean-in-elisp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Comment: Yes, those questions helped. Thanks for the help. I still answered my question just in case anyone have the same problem and doesn't have enough time to read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the concept of backquoting. Consider the following minimal configuration.  Note the usage of  `` `(...) `` and `,` within  `` `(...) ``

```
$ cat ~/.emacs.d/init.el
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages '((python . t) (shell . t)))

(setq my/path/experiments "~/trash/experimental")

(defun path/experiments (&optional file)
  (if file
      (concat my/path/experiments "/" file) my/path/experiments))

(setq org-babel-default-header-args:sh
  `((:dir . ,(path/experiments)) 
    (:tangle . ,(path/experiments "sh.sh"))))
$
```

This would cause the following behavior in an Org file

```
* My heading

** My subheading

#+begin_src sh
pwd
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /home/myname/trash/experimental

#+begin_src python :results output
import os
print(os.getcwd())
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /home/myname/location/of/this/file
```

Note that this configuration file would evaluate the expression once Emacs reaches the `setq` statements. This implies that if you change the value of the variable `my/path/experiments`, then that value will not be evaluated when obtaining the header arguments for `sh` code blocks. What I state can also be proved because of the fact that the value of `org-babel-defaul-header-args:sh` stores strings instead of expressions. As far as I know, those strings are set once Emacs reaches that statement in your configuration file or when you evaluate it.

```
org-babel-default-header-args:sh is a variable defined in ‘ob-shell.el’.
Its value is
((:dir . "~/trash/experimental")
 (:tangle . "~/trash/experimental/sh.sh"))
```

If you want to change the value of the variable, you would need to evaluate the expression that sets the header arguments again

```
(setq org-babel-default-header-args:sh
  `((:dir . ,(path/experiments)) 
    (:tangle . ,(path/experiments "sh.sh"))))
```