# Construct a list from a variable

Tags: elisp

`'(1 2 3)` gives me a list of three elements,

but

```el
(setq A "apple")
```

`'(A)` gives me `(A)`.

My question is how can I get the list `'("apple")` by referring variable A?

Comment: Tried (list A)?

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. How come there are several ways to construct a list?

Comment: Using ´, the list becomes exactly what you write. Using `list`, each argument is evaluated before added to the list. Of course, then there is backquotes that work almost like `'`, but you can use `,` and `,@` to evaluate parts of the expression.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7481/115

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*How can I get the list '("apple") by referring variable A?*

```
(list A)
```

or

```
`(,A)
```

---

*How come there are several ways to construct a list?*

1. The **`'`** in `'(A)` does **not** construct a list. The Lisp **reader** constructs a list when it reads **`(A)`**. The `'` prevents the Lisp REPL (i.e., the top-level loop) from evaluating the list that was read, so the list is just returned.
2. Function `list` also does not construct a list, directly (depending on the Lisp implementation).  The two list constructors in Lisp are `cons` and `nil` (aka `()`). Function `list` uses those two constructors: `(list)` returns `()`, and `(list X)` returns `(cons value-of-X nil)`, which is also written `(value-of-X)`.

---

The backquote syntax of `` `(,A) `` is syntactic sugar for calls to functions such as `list` and `cons`.  For example, in this case it could be an abbreviation for `(list A)`. The comma (`,`) means evaluate what follows, and the backquote (`` ` ``) means do not evaluate what follows, except for nested comma constructs.  So `` `(,A) `` could be read as "*evaluate `A` and wrap it in parens to make a singleton list*". Backquote syntax shows you a picture of what it produces. You just need to plug in (substitute) the value of whatever follows a comma.