# Use a variable's value in setq

Tags: org-mode, init-file, variables, syntax

In `emacs.el` I am using the following construct to set up an `org-remember` template:

```
(setq org-remember-templates
    '(("Todo" ?t "* TODO %^{Brief Description} %^g\n%?\nAdded: %U" "~/GTD/newgtd.org" "Tasks")
))
```

That works OK, but now I'd like to introduce parameters into this template definition. Specifically, I'd like to use a variable (or a constant) in place of `"~/GTD/newgtd.org"`

Let's say I have this definition earlier in the `emacs.el`:

`(setq todo-file (concat org-directory "todo.org"))`

How can I use thid variable `todo-file` in the `setq org-remember-templates` definition?

I have tried `'todo-file`, `"todo-file` and simply `todo-file` in place of `"~/GTD/newgtd.org"` with no luck. What is the secret to reference a variable value here?

Comment: Related/Duplicate: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7481/115

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```cl
(setq org-remember-templates
      `(("Todo"
         ?t
         "* TODO %^{Brief Description} %^g\n%?\nAdded: %U"
         ,todo-file "Tasks")))
```

It's called backquote.

Comment: That's working, but could you provide a reference to emacs docs please to learn this feature in depth? Thanks!