# String composition in elisp

Tags: fonts

I have some elisp code in my ~/.emacs which sets a variable for the default font:

```
(let ((myfont "Ubuntu Mono-13"))
  (unless (member myfont (font-family-list))
    (setq myfont "DejaVu Sans Mono-13"))
  (add-to-list 'default-frame-list '(font . myfont))
  (set-face-attribute 'default nil :font myfont))
```

however I'm having a hard time constructing the string which is the last parameter of the call to (add-to-list) such that the variable 'myfont' is evaluated. Instead of:

```
'(font . myfont)
```

I would like to send:

```
'(font . "Ubuntu Mono-13")
```

or

```
'(font . "DejaVu Sans Mono-13")
```

I've tried various things with (car), (cdr), and (concat) to no avail.

Comment: Have a look at [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list).  For your specific case, you want to use `\`(font . ,myfont)` in your config rather than `'(font . myfont)`.

Comment: or `(cons 'font myfont)`