# Simple request.el usage

Tags: eval, backquote

My embarrassingly easy question is the following:

Why does the following code works:

```el
(require 'request)

(defun geocoder ()
  (request
   "http://rpc.geocoder.us/service/csv"
   ;;; **Hardcoded parameter!**
   :params '(("address" . "1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington DC"))
   :parser 'buffer-string
   :success (function*
             (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
                (when data
                (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*request demo*")
                  (erase-buffer)
                  (insert data)
                  (pop-to-buffer (current-buffer))))))
   :error
   (function* (lambda (&key error-thrown &allow-other-keys&rest _)
                (message "Got error: %S" error-thrown)))
   ))

(geocoder)
```

While this one doesn't?

```el
(require 'request)

(defun geocoder (address) ;; adding a parameter!
  (request
   "http://rpc.geocoder.us/service/csv"
   :params '(("address" . address))
   :parser 'buffer-string
   :success (function*
             (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
                (when data
                (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*request demo*")
                  (erase-buffer)
                  (insert data)
                  (pop-to-buffer (current-buffer))))))
   :error
   (function* (lambda (&key error-thrown &allow-other-keys&rest _)
                (message "Got error: %S" error-thrown)))
   ))

;;; Now with parameter!
(geocoder "1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington DC")
```

How should I send a parameter to request?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because `'(("address" . address))` is [*quoted*](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html) (i.e. prefixed by the `'` operator), which means that what is inside does not get evaluated. The `request` function thus gets called with an argument which is the unevaluated `address` [symbol](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbols.html#Symbols) (whereas in your first implementation, the `request` function gets a string litteral, which doesn't need to be evaluated first).

You can fix this in 2 ways:

**1)** [*quasi-quoting*](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote) the argument, which allows you to get mostly the same behaviour but to specify parts which still need to be evaluated:

```
`(("address" . ,address))
```

Note that the single quote (`'`) has been replaced by a backquote (`` ` ``), and a special marker `,` was added before `address` to indicate that it should be evaluated and substituted with its value.

**2)** (as per @JordonBiondo's comment) [building the structure](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html#Building-Lists) explicitly using primitives such as `list` or `cons`. In your case, this would be done like this:

```
(list (cons "address" address))
```

where, again, `"address"` is a string literal (which evaluates to itself), and `address` gets evaluated since it is the argument in a function call.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is improving, but now I get "Wrong type argument: integerp, \," :(

Comment: Ah, ok: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html that is a backquote!!

Comment: I added links to relevant parts of the manual to make it clearer. And I also explicitly mentioned the backquote since it unsurprisingly wasn't that obvious at first sight...

Comment: alternatively you could write that as `(list (cons "address" address))` if you don't want to use backticks