# How to use text-properties in a lambda function

Tags: font-lock, text-properties, list, quote

I wish to `map` the text properties onto a list and them insert them on a new buffer. For some reason the following snippet doesn't work. I've used the `-map` utility from `dash.el` package for the map.

```
    (-map
 (lambda (x) (insert (propertize "a"
                     'font-lock-face
                     '(:foreground x))))

 '("red" "green" "orange"))
```

I wish to achieve something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with using the `dash` library, but the problem likely has to do with using a single quote for the list of face properties instead of using a backtick/comma combination.

```lisp
(mapc
  (lambda (x) (insert (propertize "a" 'face `(:foreground ,x))))
  '("red" "green" "orange"))
```

Here is an alternative to the backtick/comma list format, which uses the *function* `list`:

```lisp
(mapc
  (lambda (x) (insert (propertize "a" 'face (list :foreground x))))
  '("red" "green" "orange"))
```

---

I have not delved into the usages of the `font-lock-face` property described in the manual, so I just used `face` for this example since I am more familiar with it.  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties

---

Here are links to the manual for the quote versus the backquote:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html#Quoting

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote

Comment: `font-lock-face` is the same as `face` but is to be used when `font-lock-mode` is on, as `face` is ignored (elisp manual 22.6.6 https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Precalculated-Fontification.html#Precalculated-Fontification)

Comment: See also http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list