# Problems with setting the default font

Tags: list, backquote

I'm trying to set the default font for my Emacs based on a variable (so I can use a different font on a different machine):

```
(setq fontspec (concat ck-font-name "-" (number-to-string ck-font-size)))
(set-default-font fontspec)
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" nil
                  (font-spec :size ck-font-size :name ck-font-name))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . fontspec))
```

This basically works but the last line throws a warning:

```
frame-notice-user-settings: Invalid font: fontspec
```

I know what the problem is (`fontspec` seems to not be defined when the list gets evaluated), but I don't know how to fix this; my elisp-fu is not good enough.

Can somebody explain me or give me a pointer where I can read how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I just found out about [backquoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote):

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist `(font . ,fontspec))
```

This quotes the `(font .` part and evaluates the `fontspec`. Nice!