# Cannot use concat within org-capture template

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, quote

I am trying to use `concat` from within an `org-capture` template. But I keep getting an "Invalid template" error, so something's not right. Here is my code:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
    '(("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree "~/org/journal.org")
      (concat "* " (format-time-string "%H:%M") " %^{Title}\n\n%?"))))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, figured it out! Because the template was quoted `'(("j"...` the `concat` expression was not being evaluated. What I needed to do was use `backquote` and then insert a `,` before the `concat` statement to allow this part to evaluate:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
    `(("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree "~/org/journal.org")
      ,(concat "* " (format-time-string "%H:%M") " %^{Title}\n\n%?"))))
```

Comment: You should [accept your answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)!

Answer (score 1):

If you use concat, it seems to not update the timestamp for each entry. You can use the built in template expansion for time to make it use the current time when you capture, rather than the time the configuration file was read.

```
(setq org-capture-templates
    '(("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree "~/org/journal.org")
      "* %<%H:%M> %^{Title}\n\n%?")))
```