# Unable to set font-family from a variable

Tags: fonts

The below line works correctly:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:family "Liberation Mono")))))
```

but when I try to retrieve the font-face from a variable, it fails

```
(setq font-family-default
  "Liberation Mono")
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:family font-family-default)))))
```

Is there not a way to refer to a font-face through a variable/symbol?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a list is prefixed with an apostrophe it is non evaluated (see [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html#Quoting) in the emacs manual), this means that `custom-set-faces` sees `font-family-default` instead of the value of the variable you defined. You have to use a backtick instead of the apostrophe and add a comma before the variable to evaluate it (see [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote) in the emacs manual).

```
(setq font-family-default
      "Liberation Mono")
(custom-set-faces
 `(default ((t (:family ,font-family-default)))))
```