# Force function evaluation when setting variable value?

Tags: init-file, functions, start-up

I have these functions defined in my `early-init.el`. I'm trying to change the location of where my backups are saved and keep getting a `Wrong type argument stringp (djm/emacs-cache "backups/")`.

**`early-init.el`**

```
(Defconst user-emacs-cache "~/.cache/emacs/")

(eval-and-compile
  (defun djm/emacs-path (path)
    (expand-file-name path user-emacs-directory)))

(eval-and-compile
    (defun djm/emacs-cache (path)
           (expand-file-name path user-emacs-cache)))
```

**`init.el`**

```
(Use-package files
  :ensure nil
  :custom
  (auto-save-file-name-transforms '((".*" (djm/emacs-cache "backups/") t)))
  (backup-directory-alist '(("." . (djm/emacs-cache "backups/")))))
```

I change the place of a lot of files in my init file. How can I make something like this work without hardcoding it?

Comment: Show the complete error message, which in this case should say what type of arg was expected (versus received).

Comment: @Drew I answered my own question below where I reference that question.

Comment: Yes, I saw that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a suitable solution on another SO answer found here:

[How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

> `(quote ARG)`
>
> Return the argument, without evaluating it.  `(quote x)` yields `x`.
>   Warning: `quote` does not construct its return value, but just returns
>   the value that was pre-constructed by the Lisp reader...

Hence, you either need to [backquote](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) or use a function that evaluates the arguments.

Thus, I was able to fix the error by doing:

```
(Use-package files
  :ensure nil
  :custom
  (auto-save-file-name-transforms `((".*" ,(djm/emacs-cache "backups/") t)))
  (backup-directory-alist `(("." . ,(djm/emacs-cache "backups/")))))
```

I'm still interested in learning best practices or a more idiomatic away to achieve this. I will accept an answer showing this.

Comment: I think that what you've done is fairly idiomatic.  The backquote/unquote combination is a very standard way to achieve such things.