# eval and quotes

Tags: key-bindings, minor-mode, quote, eval, backquote

I am trying to execute the code [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferLocalKeys), which I copy below

```lisp
    (defun buffer-local-set-key (key func)
      (interactive "KSet key on this buffer: \naCommand: ")
      (let ((name (format "%s-magic" (buffer-name))))
        (eval
         `(define-minor-mode ,(intern name)
            "Automagically built minor mode to define buffer-local keys."))
        (let* ((mapname (format "%s-map" name))
               (map (intern mapname)))
          (unless (boundp (intern mapname))
            (set map (make-sparse-keymap)))
          (eval
           `(define-key ,map ,key func)))
        (funcall (intern name) t)))
```

However, when executing it like this

```
(buffer-local-set-key "C-x k" #'previous-buffer)
```

I am getting an error `eval: Symbol’s value as variable is void: func`. I suspect it is at the line `` (eval `(define-key ,map ,key func))) ``

I understand what the code is doing, but I am not sure why `eval` is being used here instead of the function being called directly, i.e. `(define-key map key func)`. However, when I tried doing that instead I got the error

`Wrong type argument: keymapp, buf-magic-map`

Can someone explain to me why `eval` might be needed here? And how to fix the error above?

I have `lexical-binding` set to true in case that was relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things wrong with the code:

- You need `#',` (or just `',`) in front of `func`.  Inside a backquote expression, just `func` would result in the literal symbol `func`, not its value as a variable. Use comma (`,` to evaluate it. But then quote that evaluated result.
- You need to use `kbd`, or else you are trying to bind the key sequence `C-x SPC k`.
- You need to lose the `t` arg when calling the minor-mode function. The minor mode is enabled when no arg is passed. See the Emacs manual, node [Minor Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minor-Modes.html):

  "If the mode command is called via Lisp, the minor mode is unconditionally **turned on if the argument is omitted** or `nil`."

```lisp
(defun buffer-local-set-key (key func)
  (interactive "KSet key on this buffer: \naCommand: ")
  (let ((name (format "%s-magic" (buffer-name))))
    (eval `(define-minor-mode ,(intern name)
             "Automagically built minor mode to define buffer-local keys."))
    (let* ((mapname (format "%s-map" name))
           (map (intern mapname)))
      (unless (boundp (intern mapname))
        (set map (make-sparse-keymap)))
      ;; Use `,' before FUNC, then quote the result of the evaluation.
      (eval `(define-key ,map ,key #',func)))
    ;; Lose the `t' arg from (funcall (intern name) t))).
    (funcall (intern name))))

;; Use `kbd'
(buffer-local-set-key (kbd "C-x k") 'previous-buffer)
```

The reason you need to use `eval` is that the result of the backquote expression is a *list*, that is, it's the resulting code in list form. You then need to evaluate that code (i.e., that list).

**UPDATE after your comment question of why use backquote at all for the second occurrence**

Yes, the second occurrence doesn't need `eval` and backquote. But you then need to use `symbol-value` to get the value of variable `map`.

```lisp
(defun buffer-local-set-key (key func)
  (interactive "KSet key on this buffer: \naCommand: ")
  (let ((name (format "%s-magic" (buffer-name))))
    (eval `(define-minor-mode ,(intern name)
             "Automagically built minor mode to define buffer-local keys."))
    (let* ((mapname (format "%s-map" name))
           (map (intern mapname)))
      (unless (boundp (intern mapname))
        (set map (make-sparse-keymap)))
      ;; Use `,' before FUNC, then quote the result of the evaluation.
      (define-key (symbol-value map) key func)) ; <== Use `symbol-value'
    ;; Lose the `t' arg from (funcall (intern name) t))).
    (funcall (intern name))))
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand that `eval` evaluates a list which is constructed in the function above. But my question was why one would use `(eval `(define-key ,map ,key #',func))` instead of `(define-key map key func)` directly. Is there an advantage to using `eval`?

Comment: Updated answer to address your comment question. See also [this Q&A](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7481/105), for using backquote with comma, to insert an evaluated value.