# How to call a function in a list and substitute its return value in the same position?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-publish

I'm trying to use the following property value in `org-publish-project-alist`

```
:html-divs ((preamble "header" "preamble")
            (content "main" (org-export-output-file-name))
            (postamble "footer" "postamble"))
```

to make the value of the `id` attribute of the `main` element the name of the org file. For example,
`<main id="index">`. However, the actual HTML output is the literal function call: `<main id="(org-export-output-file-name)">`.

The documentation for `org-export-output-file-name` says,

> Return file name as a string.

Comment: Although the specifics of this question are different, the general question has been asked before and answers abound. You can search for `backquote` or `quasiquote` here or in the emacs lisp manual. Here is a [link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list) that should help.

Comment: @NickD thank you, `(setq org-html-divs <backquote>((preamble "header" "preamble") (content "main" ,(file-name-base (org-export-output-file-name ".html"))) (postamble "footer" "postamble")))` works perfectly outside of `org-publish-project-alist` but not as the value of its `:html-divs` property. So the `id` value is the filename that contains the preceding, that is `<main id="publish-archilutes">`, but not the exported html file, for example `index`.

Comment: Sorry, you are right (IIUC which apparently is a big if): I was assuming that `org-export-output-file-name` would be able to furnish the required name at the time of the `setq` but it can only do that at the time that `org-publish` is called and processes the files to be published.

Comment: @NickD no problem, this has been helpful! Is the filename available as a variable? I can post a separate question if that's preferred.

Comment: No, I think it's constructed during exporting/publishing, so it is not available until that time. I don't think there is a need for a new question. I'll check how `:html-divs` is used at some point, but the discussion here should allow somebody else to pick up the stick and run with it.