# Is there a way to spread a list like in Typescript or Golang?

Tags: variables, list

I have a variable with some common values between `dap-mode` debug templates and I want to use that variable along with other cons elements for `:environment-variable` in languages like Golang or Typescript you would do something like this:

```
variable = [1, 2, 3]
another_variable = [...variable, 4, 5, 6]
```

then `another_variable` will carry the value of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

How can I do this in Emacs Lisp?

**EDIT:** I know how you can evaluate something inside a list, this is using the backquote, my problem was that I didn't know how Elisp processes lists in a fashion that keep the result plain because, for instance in Python, you can end with something like `[1, [2, 3, 4]]` if `x` is `[1]` and you do `x.append([2, 3, 4])`; I didn't know that `,@` was a thing and that neither `append` keeps a plain list.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Comment: @Drew absolutely not, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) mechanism in combination with `,@` to splice the value of a variable into a list; or equivalently, use `append`:

```el
(setq variable '(1 2 3))
(1 2 3)

(setq another-variable `(-2 -1 0 ,@variable 4 5 6))
(-2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6)

;; or...
(setq another-variable (append '(-2 -1 0) variable '(4 5 6)))
(-2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** A Lisp program should not try to modify [self-evaluating forms](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Self_002dEvaluating-Forms.html#Self_002dEvaluating-Forms) or [constant lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html#Quoting) (bug#40671). These are internal data structures [[Message 42](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=40671#42)].

Be aware that the final argument for `append` is not copied.

```
ELISP> (setq var1 (vector 'a 'b))
ELISP> (symbol-value 'var1)
[a b]
ELISP> (setq lst (append var1 (list 1)))
ELISP> (symbol-value 'lst)
(a b 1)
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are objecting to, since in my example I do not modify existing list structure at all. I did not read all of the [bug](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=40671) you referred to, but  AFAICT all of the examples that are discussed involve modifying  a "constant" list, which (I think) I'm not doing.  How is the fact that `append` does not copy its final argument  make any difference to the example in my answer?

Comment: @NickD: These objects are not explicitly modified, but neither should they be implicitly modifiable. You can modify the constant list through the variable: `(setcar another-variable 0 'a)`.

Comment: So what?  Are you proposing outlawing `setcar` and its ilk?

Comment: @NickD: no, I'm just saying it's better to assign a new list than a literal list. For instance, it is better to do this `(setq lst (list 'a 'b))` rather than `(setq lst '(a b))`.

Comment: @NickD: The issue is that Elisp may "merge" literal objects so IMO it is better to not store literal objects in "variables".

Comment: OK - now I understand what you are talking about: because list structure may be shared, and the shared part of list structure may include a "constant" list , which, through hash consing (or perhaps another mechanism) happens to be used by an entirely different list in some other part of emacs, then changing the "constant" list in one place will affect the other. Is that the concern?

Comment: @NickD: That's not quite right, but I think it ties in with the idea (https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=40671#414). I think this has to do with the functional paradigm, in particular to avoid undesirable side effects. The compiler or interpreter can replace some objects with references to a single object. Except that if you modify the object, you change all the other values during evaluation: a function returns the wrong value.

Comment: @NickD: See also, section "2.9 Mutability" and "10.4 Backquote" and "10.2.1 Self-Evaluating Forms" in the Elisp manual (**version 27**).