# string-join list with function as list member

Tags: quote, eval, backquote

I want to `string-join` a list of strings, one of which is returned by a function call.

Like this:

```el
(defun foobar () "foobar")
(string-join '("foo" (foobar) "bar") "|")
```

That results in `Wrong type argument: characterp, foobar` and not in `"foo|foobar|bar"` as expected.

What's the elegant way to do that?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Comment: There are multiple questions that deal with the same thing: quoting  some sexp and expecting some part of the quoted sexp to be evaluate. It would be great if Someone (TM) created a general Q & A for that, as a Community question. Many, many questions like this one have been closed as dups of the one I cited, but that Q is not stated in as general a way as it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quoted list doesn't evaluate its args, so it consists of a string, a list containing a symbol and another string. You can selectively evaluate it using backquote and unquote:

```el
`("foo" ,(foobar) "bar") ;=> ("foo" "foobar" "bar")
(string-join `("foo" ,(foobar) "bar") "|") ;=> "foo|foobar|bar"
```