# org-capture: Capture abort: Wrong type argument: stringp, org-main-file

Tags: org-mode, debugging, org-capture

I know this error has come up here before, but none of the answers thus far have been able to help me and no amount of googling has got me anywhere. I've been using org-capture-templates for quite a long while now successfully, but recently (last 2 weeks, I guess), I've been getting this error message on most - BUT NOT ALL - of the capture templates. I have tried all sorts of things to troubleshoot it, including turning on debug, using literal file paths, alternate targets, alternate templates and nothing is working.

My org config is as follows:

```
(setq org-directory "~/Documents/org-files"
      org-main-file "~/Documents/org-files/Main.org"
      org-personal-file "~/Documents/org-files/Personal.org"
      org-default-notes-file "~/Documents/org-files/Main.org"
      org-agenda-files '(org-main-file org-personal-file))

(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline org-main-file "Inbox")
         "* TODO %? %^G")
        ("d" "Todo with deadline" entry (file+headline org-main-file "Inbox")
         "* TODO %? %^G DEADLINE:%^t")
        ("s" "Scheduled Todo" entry (file+headline org-main-file "Inbox")
         "* TODO %? %^G SCHEDULED:%^t")
        ("p" "Project" entry (file+headline org-main-file "Projects")
         "* NEW %? %^G :PROPERTIES: :STATE: %^{STATE} :PM: %^{PM} :END:")
        ("i" "Idea" entry (file+headline org-main-file "Incubator")
         "* IDEA %? %^G")
        ("j" "Journal" entry (file+olp+datetree org-personal-file "Journal")
         "** %U %?")
        ("w" "Work Journal" entry (file+olp+datetree org-main-file "Journal")
         "* %U\n %?")
        ("f" "Follow Up" entry (file+headline org-main-file "Inbox")
         "** FOLLOW UP %? %^G :PROPERTIES: :ASSIGNEE: %^{ASSIGNEE} :END:")))
```

All of the above templates were working a few weeks ago and now only the 'Work Journal' and 'Journal' templates are operational. I tried creating additional templates **exactly** like the Work Journal template (with a different key and title), to no avail.

The debugger gives the following info, which I don't find to be very helpful.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Capture abort: Wrong type argument: stringp, org-m...")
  signal(error ("Capture abort: Wrong type argument: stringp, org-m..."))
  error("Capture abort: %s" "Wrong type argument: stringp, org-main-file")
  org-capture(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-capture nil)
  call-interactively(org-capture nil nil)
  command-execute(org-capture)
```

Can anyone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

MacOS Big Sur 11.1 | emacs 27.1 | Org v9.3

Comment: After some more experimentation, I noticed that the issue is tied to the '^G' template expansion symbol. Interestingly, using the local tag expansion '^g' works.

Comment: You should add the observation to your question. Does it fail before prompting you for a tag? If so, try evaluating this expression in your  `*scratch*` buffer: `(org-global-tags-completion-table (org-agenda-files))` and see if it gets an error.

Comment: @NickD, yes it fails before requesting the tags. Running that lisp in my scratch buffer I get the following error `Lisp error: (void-function org-global-tag-completion-table)`. I tried to call the function interactively as well, but it doesn't appear to be an available function. Does this mean there is something wrong with my org mode?

Comment: There is a misspelling in the name (`tag` instead of `tags`): can you try again?

Comment: Ugh... thanks for catching that. In any case, now I get `(void-function org-main-file)`. Meanwhile, if I set the `org-agenda-file` literally, it works without issue.

Comment: OK, I was blind but now I see: you are using the variable `org-main-file` in your capture template settings.  In order for that to work, you need to use the [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote) mechanism. You need to change the`'` quote  at the beginning of the value to a backquote (use the key to the left of the `1` key) and you need to put a comma in front of  each variable in the templates. This is a FAQ, e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you!