# How can a function be used as an alist value but be evaluated before its value is used?

Tags: functions, doom

I am using Chemacs2 and I want to set an environment variable  in the `.emacs-profiles.el`, eg

To clarify the problem `.emacs-profiles.el` is not executed it is read and I have updated the post with a proper sample, ie a list of lists.
It does not `provide` and is not `require`d

```lisp
    (
      ("vanilla" .((user-emacs-directory . "~/emacsen/vanilla/.emacs.d")))
      ("doom01" . ((user-emacs-directory . "~/emacsen/doom01/.emacs.d")
                   (env . (("DOOMDIR" . "~/emacsen/doom01/doomdir")
                           ("PATH" . (concat "~/emacsen/doom01/.emacs.d/bin/doom" ":" (getenv "PATH")))
                           ))))
    )
```

The file that processes it is https://github.com/plexus/chemacs2/blob/master/chemacs.el.

The profile eg `vanilla` or `doom01` is passed on the command line and its values such as `user-emacs-directory` and `env` used for that Emacs session.

The function which sets the environment variables is

```lisp
    (mapcar (lambda (env)
              (setenv (car env) (cdr env)))
            (chemacs-profile-get 'env))
```

and it fails on the pair `("PATH" . (concat "~/emacsen/doom01/.emacs.d/bin/doom" ":" (getenv "PATH")))` because `(cdr env)` which is `(concat "~/emacsen/doom01/.emacs.d/bin/doom" ":" (getenv "PATH"))` gets passed to the `setenv` call as it is without being evaluated first.

I have tried some of the splicing techniques listed at [Backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) to no avail.

If the expression in the `.emacs-profiles.el` can't be written in a better way then is there a way to rewrite `(cdr env)` in `(setenv (car env) (cdr env))` in such a way that it gets evaluated to a string before `setenv` tries to apply it?

Comment: Use `backquote` - see e.g. [this question and answers](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Comment: Never mind :-) Can you show the context? What is the relation between the code in the first box and the code in the second box? Bear in mind that I know nothing about Chemacs2 or Doom (if that is even relevant).

Comment: You say you've tried using backquote to no avail. What have you tried?

Comment: @NickD `env` is a list of environment variables for that Chemacs configuration and the setenv function requires the second parameter ie `(cdr env)` to be a string so `(concat "~/emacsen/doom01/.emacs.d/bin/doom" ":" (getenv "PATH"))` must be evaluated before it gets passed to `setenv`. I think the problem comes from the fact that `.emacs-profile.el` is not executed, it is `read` and that is probably why it is not evaluated. `setenv` probably reads the raw expression then evaluates it. I will update the question.

Comment: Please do: this sounds like a typical problem where `backquote` is the solution, so more details will help.

Comment: When I start with `--debug-init` the error the debugger displays is `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument characterp concat)`. My conclusion is that the Chemacs code `reads` the expression and does not evaluate it, so the `(cdr env)` value passed to `setenv` is the raw symbol from the `read` and thus fails because it is not a string expression.

Comment: That is a correct diagnosis I think.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that what you need is a generator function that will run your code and generate a file in the proper format. One way to do this is with literate programming in Org mode. A simple org document can run your lisp and produce the proper output, and updating the document for new values can automatically create the new file for you. Essentially, you never touch the `.el` file itself.