# Function argument does not seem to be visible inside of function

Tags: quote, backquote

I use this code (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14454756/5091709)) to highlight a single line in black:

```
(defun find-overlays-specifying (prop pos)
  (let ((overlays (overlays-at pos))
        found)
    (while overlays
      (let ((overlay (car overlays)))
        (if (overlay-get overlay prop)
            (setq found (cons overlay found))))
      (setq overlays (cdr overlays)))
    found))

(defun highlight-or-dehighlight-line ()
  (if (find-overlays-specifying
       'line-highlight-overlay-marker
       (line-beginning-position))
      (remove-overlays (line-beginning-position) (+ 1 (line-end-position)))
    (let ((overlay-highlight (make-overlay
                              (line-beginning-position)
                              (+ 1 (line-end-position)))))
        (overlay-put overlay-highlight 'face '(:background "black"))
        (overlay-put overlay-highlight 'line-highlight-overlay-marker t))))

(global-set-key [f9] (lambda () (interactive) (highlight-or-dehighlight-line)))
```

Now I want to make it more generic because I want to be able to use a few different colors. So I added a parameter `color` to function `highlight-or-dehighlight-line`, replaced `"black"` with `color`, and passed `"black"` to `highlight-or-dehighlight-line`:

```
(defun find-overlays-specifying (prop pos)
  (let ((overlays (overlays-at pos))
        found)
    (while overlays
      (let ((overlay (car overlays)))
        (if (overlay-get overlay prop)
            (setq found (cons overlay found))))
      (setq overlays (cdr overlays)))
    found))

(defun highlight-or-dehighlight-line (color)
  (if (find-overlays-specifying
       'line-highlight-overlay-marker
       (line-beginning-position))
      (remove-overlays (line-beginning-position) (+ 1 (line-end-position)))
    (let ((overlay-highlight (make-overlay
                              (line-beginning-position)
                              (+ 1 (line-end-position)))))
        (overlay-put overlay-highlight 'face '(:background color))
        (overlay-put overlay-highlight 'line-highlight-overlay-marker t))))

(global-set-key [f9] (lambda () (interactive) (highlight-or-dehighlight-line "black")))
```

However, this does not seem to do anything and I cannot find my mistake. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is here: `'(:background color)`. This is quoted, so it is simply treated literally. The result is a list containing two elements, the keyword `:background` and the symbol `color`. One solution is to use a backquote, or quasi–quote, so that you can interpolate values into the list:

```lisp
`(:background ,color)
```

Another solution is to call a function instead, since the arguments to the function will be evaluated:

```lisp
(list :background color)
```

The first is more idiomatic, but both will get you a list containing the keyword `:background` followed by the value assigned to the variable named `color`, rather than the literal symbol `color`.

See [chapter 10.4 Backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) in the Emacs Lisp manual. You can open the Info viewer inside of Emacs to read this manual with `C-h i`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That would've taken me ages to figure out.

Comment: You’re welcome!