# Why is :box on set-face-attribute not getting the current value from (face-background)?

Tags: quote, backquote

Why is `:box` not getting the current background color?. It doesn't even work if I `setq` a variable with the color hardcoded, but if I set the hex color as a literal it works perfectly. If I evaluate manually the sexp `(face-background 'default)` it returns the right color #1E1C31 ( a dark color, but if you notice on the screenshot is setting a bright color ).

```lisp
(set-face-attribute 'tab-bar-tab-inactive nil
  :family "Cascadia"
  :foreground (face-foreground 'default)
  :background (face-background 'default)
  :height 1.3
  :slant 'italic
  :box '(:line-width 9 :color (face-background 'default))
```

```
                        )
```

[image]

In my opinion my question is not exactly the same as this one:
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7487/7006

In both cases the solution could be solved creating a list, but in this case as @db48x explained there's an alternate solution with quasiquoting that the other answers discourage the use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Comment: This question gets asked relatively frequently, in slightly different forms. It's essentially based on misunderstanding `quote`.

Comment: That question helps with this answer to understand the concept of `quote`, but with @db48x answer it makes more sense on using (or not using in this case ) of `quotes` on the attributes of the `:box` face

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you put it inside of a quote.

```lisp
'(:line-width 9 :color (face-background 'default)
```

This is quoted, so it is not evaluated. It is simply a list of four things. The last one in the list is another list with the symbol `face-background` and the list `(quote default)` in it.

There are a couple of ways you could write this so that will be evaluated. Use the `list` function, which constructs a list out of its arguments:

```lisp
(list :line-width 9 :color (face-background 'default))
```

Use quasiquoting instead:

```lisp
`(:line-width 9 :color ,(face-background 'default))
```

This lets you use the comma operator (`,`) to interpolate a value from an expression that will be evaluated.

See [chapter 10.3 Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html) and [chapter 10.4 Backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual for more information.