# How to use a variable for an output :file path for call-process

Tags: spacemacs, backquote, call-process

I'm using [call-process](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html#index-call_002dprocess) in an emacs/lisp file (in Spacemacs) to run an external command and write its output to a file. It works when I hard code the path like this:

```list
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file "/Users/alan/Desktop/tmp.txt"))
```

However, I can't get it to work when I use a variable for the path.

When I do:

```list
(defvar path-to-output-test nil
  "Path to send the file to")

(setq path-to-output-test
      "/Users/alan/Desktop/tmp-4.txt"
      )

(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file path-to-output-test))
```

I get:

```
setq: Wrong type argument: stringp, path-to-output-test
```

I tried setting the variable directly with:

```list
(defvar path-to-output-test
  "/Users/alan/Desktop/tmp-4.txt"
  "Path to send the file to")
```

And by adding a `concat` with:

```list
(setq path-to-output-test
      (concat "/Users/alan/Desktop/tmp-5.txt" )
      )
```

I also tried a bunch of other combinations:

```list
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file path-to-output-test))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file 'path-to-output-test))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file `path-to-output-test))

(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '((:file path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '((:file 'path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '((:file `path-to-output-test)))

(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '('(:file path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '('(:file 'path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '('(:file `path-to-output-test)))

(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(stringp (:file 'path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(stringp '(:file 'path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(stringp `(:file 'path-to-output-test)))

(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file (string path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file '(string path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file `(string path-to-output-test)))

(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file (stringp path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file '(stringp path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file `(stringp path-to-output-test)))

(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file (make-string path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file '(make-string path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file `(make-string path-to-output-test)))

(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file (make-string 'path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file '(make-string 'path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file `(make-string 'path-to-output-test)))

(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file (prin1 path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file '(prin1 path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file `(prin1 path-to-output-test)))

(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file (concat path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file '(concat path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil '(:file `(concat path-to-output-test)))

(call-process "/bin/ls" nil `(:file path-to-output-test))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil `(:file 'path-to-output-test))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil `(:file `path-to-output-test))
```

None of those worked. They all returned a similar error but with whatever code I was trying to use for the iteration.

These tries didn't throw an error, but they didn't output the file:

```list
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil (stringp '(:file path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil (stringp '(:file 'path-to-output-test)))
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil (stringp '(:file `path-to-output-test)))
```

I'm new to emacs/lisp and am out of ideas at this point.

Comment: This is a FAQ with many duplicates, which are unfortunately a bit hard to find unless you know the answer already. Here is one: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Comment: Maybe? I'm still trying to parse the answer you linked. The below accepted answer did work. I didn't understand it, but someone was kind enough to explain it, so I'm starting to get my head around it

Comment: Yes, it is unfortunately a bit of a hydra: you see all the heads waving but initially not the body until you have some experience. But the body is: how can I get the value of a variable inside a quoted list? You need to quote the list (because it's just data, not a function call), but you want to evaluate *parts* of that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html)

```lisp
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil `(:file ,path-to-output-test))
```

or `list` directly

```lisp
(call-process "/bin/ls" nil (list :file path-to-output-test))
```