# Problems using a function reference from a plist

Tags: functions, funcall, plists

I'm trying to `(funcall)` a function reference I have in a plist.

```lisp
(defun helper-get-filename ()
  "Argument Helper to get a filename."
  (read-file-name "-l <filename>: " "~/"))

(let ((plist  '(:flag "-l" :arg-helper #'helper-get-filename)))
  (funcall (plist-get plist  :arg-helper)))
```

However, Emacs debugger responds with:

```lisp
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function #'helper-get-filename)
  #'helper-get-filename()
  funcall(#'helper-get-filename)
  (let ((plist '(:flag "-l" :arg-helper #'helper-get-filename))) (funcall (plist-get plist :arg-helper)))
  eval((let ((plist '(:flag "-l" :arg-helper #'helper-get-filename))) (funcall (plist-get plist :arg-helper))) nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eros-eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eros-eval-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eros-eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eros-eval-last-sexp)
```

How is this done properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Comment: Not specifically.  But thanks for adding the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `'helper-get-filename` is not a valid function name, `helper-get-filename` is. You are doubly quoting the function name.

Your code should have been:

```lisp
(let ((plist '(:flag "-l" :arg-helper helper-get-filename)))
  (funcall (plist-get plist  :arg-helper)))

;;; or

(let ((plist (list :flag "-l" :arg-helper #'helper-get-filename)))
  (funcall (plist-get plist  :arg-helper)))

;;; Or backquote so 
;;; #' can keep the compiler happy.

(let ((plist `(:flag "-l" :arg-helper ,#'helper-get-filename)))
  (funcall (plist-get plist  :arg-helper)))
```

Comment: Oh, cool, I thought I'd tried that, but must have not re-eval'ed my plist properly in the actual code before I wrote up the example.  Good to know I don't need to quote it.

Comment: Can you add on the backquote style too, for future readers.  Thank you. (Added)

Comment: @ocodo Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So the correct answer is don't use `quote` - `'`

Instead `backquote` the list structure or use the `list` function.

Using `list`

```
(defun helper-get-filename ()
  "Argument Helper to get a filename."
  (read-file-name "-l <filename>: " "~/"))

(let ((plist (list :flag "-l" :arg-helper #'helper-get-filename)))
  (funcall (plist-get plist  :arg-helper)))
```

or for brevity use the backquote style.  It will also keep the bytecode compiler happy and avoid a missing function reference at compile time.

```
(defun helper-get-filename ()
  "Argument Helper to get a filename."
  (read-file-name "-l <filename>: " "~/"))

(let ((plist `(:flag "-l" :arg-helper ,#'helper-get-filename)))
  (funcall (plist-get plist  :arg-helper)))
```

Comment: @terrytsao has the correct answer. as in the simplest, with the least line noise.  Thanks again Terry.

Comment: I prefer your answer, because `#'foo` is better than `'foo`, because the byte compiler can complain when `foo` is not known to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

I could hold a reference to the function in the plist as a string and do:

```
(funcall (intern "helper-get-filename"))
```

*That does make me cringe a little bit, and I'm sure there's a **correct** way to do this.*

(And there is! The accepted answer has 2 good, and one best way, backquote the top level containing list and use `,#'helper-get-filename` for the function reference in the example.  You can evaluate any variable this way too to include their results in the list)

Comment: this answer should be downvoted.

Comment: If you think it is not useful, you could delete it.

Comment: I think it's useful to record options i wouldn't recommend.

Comment: There are way too many bad ways to do something, so recording them is probably not necessary and maybe even harmful. But I was just pointing out the option: use it only if you think that's the right thing to do.

Comment: Given the context I see no harm in the answer or it's wording.  I need reminders of these things myself.