# left and top for initial-frame-alist using cons variable

Tags: frames

I am using a variable storing a cons cell

```
(defvar typex-frame-position (cons 1270 1223))
```

Followed by

```
(setq initial-frame-alist
  '((left . (car typex-frame-position))
    (top . (cdr typex-frame-position))
    (width . 73) (height . 21)))
```

But, the only way I get the frame at the correct position is to hardwire the numbers like this.

```
(setq initial-frame-alist
  '((left . 1270)
    (top . 1223)
    (width . 73) (height . 21)))
```

How can I use the values from `typex-frame-position`?

Comment: I do not understand the description about backward quote, why I have to use it, and how to use it in my case.

Comment: What about this one? [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Comment: It is not helping at all.  Because they relate to things that are different from what I am doing and fail to understand how to apply what you are saying.  I need an explanation of the solution and why it is needed, but has to be direct on what I am doing here.

Comment: The `'` suppresses evaluation, allowing you to write a literal list. but `(car typex-frame-position)` is an expression that you want to evaluate. So you need to use ` instead: `((left ,(car …)) …)).

Comment: In more simple terms, the quoting in front of the list passed to `initial-frame-alist` suppresses any evaluation.  Meaning that `(car typex-frame-position)` is not evaluated, and consequently the value of the expression does not get associated with `left`.  Using `,` allows `(car typex-frame-position)` to be evaluated to the value `1270`.  Right?

Comment: Right, but you can only use a `,` inside of a backquoted expression. Using it inside an ordinary quoted expression doesn’t work.

Comment: I understand how things work now.

Comment: It works very well, and things function as planned.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but this thing is not described in the Emacs Lisp Tutorial.

Comment: Nope. It is described in the Emacs Lisp Manual though.

Comment: Would the backquote also be applicable if instead of `(car typex-frame-position)`, I had a variable like `fxpos` ?

Comment: Yes, you would put the comma in front of any expression of any type that you wanted to be evaluated instead of quoted.

Comment: Thusly, doing `(left . ,fxpos)` would evaluate to the value `1270`.

Answer (score 0):

Summary of discussion with @db48x

Quoting in front of the list passed to `initial-frame-alist` suppresses any evaluation - meaning that `(car typex-frame-position)` is not evaluated.

In addition to quote a list, tho Backquote construct allows one to evaluate expressions by using the comma marker.

Thus

```
(setq initial-frame-alist
  `((left . ,(car typex-frame-position))
    (top . ,(cdr typex-frame-position))
    (width . 73) (height . 21)))
```