# Why doesn't stringp evaluate the expression in this case?

Tags: variables, string, symbols, eval

I'm relatively new to Elisp and I'm trying to figure out a bug in my code, but I have no idea what to search or read in order to get an idea about it.

The bug is in this code:

```lisp
(defvar some-variable "some-value")
(setq some-plist
      '(:name "name" :query some-variable :key 97))

(stringp (plist-get some-plist :query))  ;; nil (HERE)
(stringp some-variable) ;; t
```

Even though `(plist-get some-plist :query)` returns `some-variable`, why does `stringp` on it returns `nil`?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "unquote" `some-variable` when building the plist. So the code should look like this:

```lisp
(defvar some-variable "some-value")
(setq some-plist
      `(:name "name" :query ,some-variable :key 97))

(stringp (plist-get some-plist :query))  ;; t (HERE)
(stringp some-variable) ;; t
```

When you build a list using a quote `'`, everything is added to the list verbatim. So, going back to the snippet you posted, even though `some-variable` evaluates to a string, `'(some-variable)` is equivalent to `(list 'some-variable)` (a list with a quoted symbol).

To get what you are asking for, you can either use a backtick-quoted list and unquote `some-variable`

```
`(,some-variable)
```

or just use the `list` form

```
(list some-variable)
```

Comment: Generally speaking, it is convenient to construct a property list using `list`  instead of [backquoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html), since keyword symbols are self-evaluating, so you don't need to quote them, and it is fairly common to want to evaluate the values in a plist anyway.

Comment: That certainly makes sense. Thanks for the tip.