# Naming problem when using tabulated-list-print

Tags: tabulated-list-mode

I want to print an alist with a title consisting of a key title `keytl` and a value title `valtl` before printing the values using `tabulated-list-print`.

```
(defun tlprint-alist (alist &optional outbufr keytl valtl)
  "Print an associated list via `tabulated-list-print'."

  (let*
      ( (bufr (or outbufr (get-buffer-create "*Alist*")))
        (keytl (or keytl "Key Title"))
        (valtl (or valtl "Value Title")) )

    (with-current-buffer bufr
      (setq tabulated-list-format [(keytl 20 t) (valtl 20 t)])
      (setq tabulated-list-sort-key (cons keytl nil))
      (setq tabulated-list-entries
            (cons (list keytl valtl)
                  (mapcar (lambda (pair)
                            (list (car pair) (cdr pair)))
                          alist)))
      (tabulated-list-print) )))
```

Running

```
(setq foo '((a . ["a1" "a2"]) (b . ["b1" "b2"]) (c . ["c1" "c2"])))
(tlprint-alist foo)
```

gives

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "No column named Key Title")
  signal(error ("No column named Key Title"))
  error("No column named %s" "Key Title")
  tabulated-list--column-number("Key Title")
  tabulated-list--get-sorter()
  tabulated-list-print()
```

Comment: What is the problem that is stopping you from doing this?  Is it a question of getting the values of some variable into `tabulated-list-format`?  If so, please say so in the question!

Comment: What @FranBurstall said. A guess is that you're looking for this: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7481.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
(defun tlprint-alist (alist &optional outbufr keytl valtl)
  "Print an associated list via `tabulated-list-print'."

  (let*
      ((bufr (or outbufr (get-buffer-create "*Alist*")))
       (keytl (or keytl "Key Title"))
       (valtl (or valtl "Value Title")))

    (with-current-buffer bufr
      (tabulated-list-mode)
      (setq tabulated-list-format (vector (list keytl 20 t) (list valtl 20 t)))
      (setq tabulated-list-sort-key (cons keytl nil))
      (setq tabulated-list-entries
        (mapcar (lambda (pair)
              (list (car pair) (cdr pair)))
            alist))
      (tabulated-list-init-header)
      (tabulated-list-print))))
```

Four issues arise in your code:

1. You need to ensure that `keytl` and `valtl` get evaluated when setting `tabulated-list-format`.
2. `(list keytl valtl)` is not of the right format to go into `tabulated-list-entries` and is not the way to get a header-line.
3. You should put the target buffer in `tabulated-list-mode`.
4. Most important: you need to call `tabulated-list-init-header` to get the header.

Commentary: I found out what was missing from your code by experimenting with it in the scratch buffer and reading the manual section on `tabulated-list-mode` (24.2.7).  I urge you to adopt the same strategy before posting here.

Comment: I do not get the header though, just the values.

Comment: That is very strange because I get the header and values.   Try this in a fresh emacs session to make sure that you are using the right version of the function (I have just now copy/pasted the function from my answer along with the data and function call from your question into the scratch buffer, evaluated the lot and got the desired table).

Comment: I am using GNU Emacs 29.0.50

Comment: Have added `(insert "TEST")` just before `(tabulated-list-mode)`.  But that is not getting printed either.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that calling `(tlprint-alist foo)` twice gives `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (buffer-read-only #<buffer *Alist*>) insert("TEST")`

Comment: I am using GNU Emacs 29.0.91 but also tested this on 28.2.