# Evaluating variable for mode-line face attribute

Tags: eval

I have the following code that changes `mode-line` colours.  When using the `:box` property I want to use a variable.  But I get an error using `:color fglamp` because I need to evaluate the colour variable.  How may I solve this ?

```
(set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
  :background bglamp
  :foreground fglamp
  :inverse-video nil
  :box '(:line-width 3 :color fglamp :style nil)) )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the variables before adding them to a list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7481/how-to-evaluate-the-variables-before-adding-them-to-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using the `:box` property I want to use a variable. ... I need to evaluate the colour variable.

Since you want to change the value (actually the face attribute) dynamically:

```lisp
(progn
  (add-variable-watcher 'VARIABLE-NAME
                        (lambda (symbol newval operation where)
                          (set-face-attribute ...
                                              :box `( :color ,newval
                                                      ...))))
  (set-face-attribute ...
                      :box `( :color ,VARIABLE-NAME
                              ...)))
```

---

`add-variable-watcher` has limitations, please `C-h f` it.

Comment: The `add-variable-watcher` is an unnecessary complication: the OP only wanted to propagate whatever value `fglamp` has into the quoted expression. So only the `backquote` part is relevant to the question I believe.

Comment: @NickD: I am not sure -- I thought he wants to give the face attribute a variable instead of a value. E.g., `(setq a b)` then if `(setq b xxx)`, the value of `a` will change to `xxx` as well. don't know whether I made this clear...

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating the question: and if so, the question is a frequent duplicate. See marked duplicate, although there are tens of othe instances.

Comment: @NickD: I guess this question is not about *backquote*, because OP uses *backquote* in his last question -- he knows how to use it.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree :-)

Comment: Just because he uses backquote (in a `custom-set-faces` moreover) does not mean that he knows how to use it: I suspect that if you look for `custom-set-faces`  on Emacs SE you will always find it used with a backquote, so it is much more likely that he cut-and-pasted that construct without understanding it.